# Fizz Buzz function that returns an array

Tags: javascript, beginner, fizzbuzz

I am a newbie to JS and I am working on a FizzBuzz challenge. Below is what I have tried. Essentially when the function takes a value then it would iterate from 1 up to the value and an array would result.

I am seeking advice on adding conditional checking such as:

1. If the value of `n` is less than 4, it will return the string: "Please insert a value greater than or equal to 4".
2. If the function is passed no value, it should return an empty array.

I am not sure where to add and should I be using `if`...`else` or simply `if` for each conditional checking.

```
var fizzBuzz = function(n, arr = []) {   
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  if (n === 1) {                         
    arr.push('1');
    return arr.reverse();
  } else {                               
    if (n % 4 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('FIZZBUZZ');
    } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('Buzz');
    } else if (n % 4 === 0) {
      arr.push('Fizz');
    } else {
      arr.push('' + n);
    }
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1, arr);         
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. I voted to close because this code does not work at all, `fizzBuzz(20)` returns `undefined`. Also Fizz is every 3, not every 4.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Code Review isn't about helping you modify your code for new requirements, it is about helping you to see better logic. We Review code here, Code that is already written and fulfilling all requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> I am hoping to seek advice on adding conditional checking such as: 1) if the value n is less than 4, it will return the string: "Please insert a value greater than or equal to 4" and 2) if the function is passed no value, it should return an empty array. I am not sure where to add and should I be using if...else or simply if for each conditional checking.

If we check for `n < 4` and returns a fixed string `"Please insert a value greater than or equal to 4"` anyway, do we really need to do anything before it? If we don't need to do anything before it, where should we put it?

Same goes for `2) if the function is passed no value, it should return an empty array`

---

For the code itself, some points

**1.** Let's look at the loop

```js
for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  if (n === 1) {                         
    // blah
    return arr.reverse();
  } else {                               
    // blah
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1, arr);         
  }
}
```

On every iteration this will return something. The `for` loop won't even need to go through the next iteration, it will always break and `return` on any iteration(!). You are doing recursion and loop at the same time.

**2.** `arr.push('' + n);`

Maybe use `toString()` method for numbers `arr.push(n.toString());`

**3.** `if-else` and returns

```js
if (n === 1) {                         
    arr.push('1');
    return arr.reverse();
} else {   
    // blah    
}
```

Since the `if` block will always return, we don't need the `else`. This can be rewritten as

````js
if (n === 1) {                         
    arr.push('1');
    return arr.reverse();
}
  
// the else blah    
```
````